# How to parse logs using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elk

I have such message to be parsed by grok filters:

> "@timestamp":"2019-12-16T08:57:33.804Z","@version":"1","message":"[Optional[admin]]
>   (0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0) 9999 approve
>   2019-12-16T08:57:30.414732Z","logger_name":"com.company.asd.asd.web.rest.MyClass","thread_name":"XNIO-1
>   task-5","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"app_name":"asd","instance_id":"asd-123","app_port":"8080","version":"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

I tried http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to parse my logs and i wrote such regexp to do it:

> "@timestamp":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTime}","@version":"%{INT:version}","message":"[\D*[%{WORD:login}]]
>   (%{IPV4:forwardedFor}\, %{IPV4:remoteAddr}\|%{IPV4:remoteAddr})
>   %{WORD:identificator} %{WORD:methodName}
>   %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:actionaDate}%{GREEDYDATA:all}

it seems working in this debugger, but when i try to add this line to my filter in .conf file everything it writes is _grokparsefailure and my message remains unchanged, my filter:

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => { "message" => ""@timestamp":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTime}","@version":"%{INT:version}","message":"\[\D*\[%{WORD:login}]\] \(%{IPV4:forwardedFor}\, %{IPV4:remoteAddr}\|%{IPV4:remoteAddr}\) %{WORD:identificator} %{WORD:methodName} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:actionaDate}%{GREEDYDATA:all}" }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below grok,

```
filter {
   grok {
        match => { "message" => "\"@timestamp\":\"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTime}\",\"@version\":\"%{INT:version}\",\"message\":\"\[\D*\[%{WORD:login}]\] \(%{IPV4:forwardedFor}\, %{IPV4:remoteAddr}\|%{IPV4:remoteAddr}\) %{WORD:identificator} %{WORD:methodName} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:actionaDate}%{GREEDYDATA:all}" }
    }

}
```